# How to make a comma separated list of array values?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have the following documents

1. User Schema:

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    email: { type: String, lowercase: true },
    offers: [],
    anyCountry: {type: Boolean, default: false},
    city: String,
});
```

2. Tags Schema

```
var TagSchema = new Schema({
    text: String,
    dateCreated: { type: Date, default: Date.now}
});
```

I am aggregating it this way:

```
User.aggregate(
    {$match: {
        $or: [
            {'isBlocked': false},
            {'isBlocked': {$exists: false}}
        ]}},
    { $project: {"offers": 1, _id: 0, city: 1, name: 1}},
    { $unwind: "$offers" },
    {
        $match: {
            $and: [
                {'offers': { $not: { $size: 0} }},
                {'offers.type': type}
            ]
        }
    },
    { $sort: {"offers.dateCreated": -1} },
    function (err, result) {
        if (!err) {
            return res.json({status: 'success', data: result});
        } else {
            return res.send(err);
        }
    }
)
```

The output is ok, but it contains tags as array. What I need is:

1. to have array values assigned to a computed field "offers.tagsList" as a coma separated sting `{offers.tagsList = 'tag1, tag2, tag3, ...'}`.
2. check if filed `offers.anyCountry` doesn't exists and add it to the output with value `false`.

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you want a comma separated string in here? Surely an array is the more natural form. It's also very unclear what the content of "offers" is since this is not strictly defined in your schema. And it's very unclear as to the relation of "tags" here, or what data if any about "tags" is contained in the offers array.

Comment: Tags are shown as a coma separated list in the frontend. Since tags array contains objects {title: 'some title', value:'some value'}. I have to iterate through this array in the frontend and create a list of coma separated values. I thought I could avoid it creating needed response structure on db level.